# How get inputs value for validate

Tags: jquery, arrays, input

I have form

```
<div class = "required">
 <div class = 'myclass'>
  <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="" class="anotherclass">
 </div>
</div>
<div class = "required">
 <div class = 'myclass'>
  <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" value="" class="anotherclass">
 </div>
</div>
<div class>
 <div class = 'myclass'>
  <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="" class="anotherclass">
 </div>
</div>
```

I want get all elements with class "required", and get input value inside this div, then validete value. I can get value one element by id, but I want try to get the values of children selected by the class of parents. I get array by

```
 var form = $('.required :input')
```

but I can't get inputs value. Use array index or each return error.

```
 form[0].val();

Uncaught TypeError: form[0].val is not a function
```

Please help me, where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a loop to retrieve the value of each input individually from the collection in the jQuery object. To do that you can use `each()` and `val()`:

```js
$('.required :input').each(function() {
  let val = $(this).val();
  console.log(val);
  
  // validate here...
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="required">
  <div class="myclass">
    <input type="text" name="login" id="login" value="lorem" class="anotherclass">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="required">
  <div class="myclass">
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass" value="ipsum" class="anotherclass">
  </div>
</div>
<div class>
  <div class="myclass">
    <input type="text" name="comment" id="commnt" value="dolor" class="anotherclass">
  </div>
</div>
```

With regard to the error you see, it's because accessing a jQuery object by index, ie; `$('.foo')[0]` returns a Element object, not a jQuery object, and they do not have a `val()` method.

Answer (score 1):

using brackets like [0] converts a jquery object to DOMElement. So you need one of these syntaxes:

Javascript:

```
 form[0].value
```

or stay on Jquery:

```
 form.eq(0).val()
```